# Textbox for WHERE clause for C# Datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

(VS 2010 C# Website) I have TextBox1 to filter FirstNames in a SQL database that will be displayed in a Datagrid, but I can't figure out the proper way to link the user input from the "TextBox1.Text" into the WHERE clause for the Datagrid filtering. I've tried:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TestName] WHERE ([TestFirstName] LIKE '%' + TextBox1.Text + '%')"
```

Comment: SQL is not a dbms, do you mean MS SQL-Server instead?   What does _"it's still wrong"_ mean? Do you get an exception? Is this ASP.NT or Winforms? Are you using ADO.NET  to connect to your database, can you show more code?

Comment: Looks like a WebForms `SqlDataSource`. You should be able to use a control parameter in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TestName] WHERE ([TestFirstName] LIKE '%' + @TestFirstName2 + '%')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="TestFirstName2" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TestName] WHERE ([TestFirstName] LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%')"
```

Notice the quotes around + TextBox1.Text +. Your example above seems to be looking for the literal string TextBox1.Text, not the actual value of TextBox1.Text.

Comment: TextBox1.Text = "*; drop table users;" - It's better to use parameters :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [TestName] WHERE ([TestFirstName] LIKE '% " + TextBox1.Text + "%')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding data to your datagrid with a SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource, you can simple put your WHERE Clause into the "FilterExpression" property of the DataSource you're using.

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            string filterstr = "";

            if (this.tbSearchEmpID.Text.Trim() != String.Empty)
            {
                filterstr += "EmpId LIKE '%" + this.tbSearchEmpID.Text.Trim() + "%'";
            }

            this.ObjectDataSource1.FilterExpression = filterstr;
        }
```